# How could this compile be push git and indenting?

Tags: git, github

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 361 bytes | 361.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), completed with 3 local objects.
To https://github.com
   077ae4e..28d685d  master -> master
```

Por completarte me rompí en pedazos
Me lo advirtieron, pero no hice caso
Me di cuenta que lo tuyo es falso
Fue la gota que rebalsó el vaso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you've not set a media query correctly. Please try it with

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
}
```

and see if this works.

Comment: It is set correctly - I have used this version (without the extra specifications) many times and that is not the issue in this case... Of course I checked adding the specifications before posting a question here - and nothing changed...

Comment: I guessed you'd be missing `}` at some point even though you closed your overall query.